# NetworkX - Plot Graphs without labels

Tags: python-2.7, graph, graphviz, networkx, jupyter-notebook

I have a set of nodes and edges in a graph. 460 nodes total, 7606 edges total.

The nodes have long names, and I'm having trouble having the graph be plotted without those long names obscuring the graph.

For example here is a sample node name: `A/mallard/Interior Alaska/9BM1974/2009(H4N6)` (the influenza crowd, if it exists here, will be familiar with this naming)

And I have an image that illustrates the problem I'm facing [image: here].

The code I have used to create the figure is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
nx.draw_networkx(G)
plt.show()
```

Does anybody know how I can draw the graphs without having all these labels associated with it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
    nx.draw_networkx(G,with_labels=False)
```

will turn off the labels on the nodes.

Comment: Many thanks, Vikram! Where in the documentation does `with_labels` show up? I can't find it in there...

Comment: You could see that [here](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html)

Comment: Ahhhh! A lesson for me in not skimming the documentation... Thanks again, Vikram! :-)